Replacing Electric Range with Gas Range
Recently purchased a house and it has an electric range/oven in an island. I much prefer cooking with gas, and am curious about the logistics of a gas range/oven on an island. A few background facts..

There is gas service to the house, and a gas line actually runs right beneath the kitchen island, so connecting a gas range would likely be pretty painless. EDIT: This would be done professionally, painless just refers to the amount of time/money

There is a pot rack above the island that I would love to keep, but I understand that downdraft ventilation + gas range = carbon monoxide poisoning. Looking at mounting a ductless hood above the island, but I’m not sure about the efficiency - my partner cooks with high heat and I’ve heard ductless hoods tend to get worse as the flames get higher, so to speak.

The island comes off an exterior wall - while we don’t have any existing ductwork (no central AC) would it be possible to run a duct along the ceiling and through the exterior wall? This would be probably 5-6ft of ductwork. We have 9ft ceilings, so I think it would be possible to keep it clean and neat without having to cut into the ceiling.


Is this a feasible project? Reconfiguring the kitchen is way out of my budget right now, but I’m hoping I could save up for this in the next year or so.

First check a law. There is possibility that gas is prohibited/taxed in Your country. Maybe is allowed use actual gas instalation only for next 1-3-5-10 years but no conversion from electrical to gas. Then check what airduct, fire safety and so You need to have to have gas range.

I would consider hooking the range up to the gas line to be a job for a professional (too many ways that a small error can result in boom), but otherwise it looks feasible. I would anyway use dedicated ducts for the range hood.

Have you looked at induction ranges lately?  They offer many of the advantages of gas (instant response, high effective power) without the need for gas, and have other tricks up their sleeve as well (good ones have more finesse than any other range tech, and they're far easier to clean since they generally don't cook spills onto their surface)

Ductless hood is really no hood at all—might as well just hang a box fan from the ceiling.


assuming the legality is not an issue then that should be fine.

ductless has the same core issue with regards to gas as downdraft, which is that it doesn't vent the combustion products to the outside. Which can result in carbon monoxide.

you can make a clean looking encasement to surround the duct itself, and also run power through it from the wall. The encasement can then be a base for mounting other fancy things like a pot rack.


